# What characters to escape on cmd to work with Xidel scripting

Tags: cmd, xidel

Using [Xidel](https://github.com/benibela/xidel) to scrape HTML:

```
for /f "usebackqDELIMS=" %a in (`^"xidel -s file.html -e 'json(//script[@type="application/ld+json"])/(string)()'^"`) do set "string=%a"
```

When running it in CMD output gives:

> /(string)()'"`) was unexpected at this time.

I assume I need to escape some characters, following this documentation http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php I tried lots of options, using carrots for various characters and backslash for [], but keep getting more errors.

Is there a certain one character that needs escaping or more or this isn't the case at all?

Comment: If you're trying to use this in a batch script, your first issue is that you need to change `%a` to `%%a`. Secondly, `(`` & ``)` Need to be changed to `('` & `')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now [I wrongfully assumed you were on Linux](https://github.com/benibela/xidel/issues/25). In that case you have to fix the quoting (see [Examples](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) #9 and #10):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel -s file.html -e "json(//script[@type='application/ld+json'
])/(string)()"') DO SET "string=%%A"
```

or

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel -s file.html -e "string:=json(//script[@type='application/
ld+json'])/(string)()" --output-format^=cmd') DO %%A
```

to have Xidel assign the variable for you.

Comment: Any idea why it spams it out results in separate strings, instead of all in one string? Now it sets a string new per line, so technically only last string is saved.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the Github-issue. Then you probably forgot to string-join the genre items: `... -e "string:=json(//script[@type='application/ld+json'])/join((genre)(),', ')" ...`.
Btw, could you thumbs up this answer if you're happy with it? (and close the Github-issue the same way)

Comment: it works on cmd, but when I include it on final batch script, it gives `the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect` error.